# js split only until first given char

Tags: javascript, regex

I got the following String

> var intNote = "08.03.2018 09:53:37 - Mustermann, Max (Work notes) Work note internal"

which I manipulate the following way:

```
        var tempArr = intNote.split('-');
        var tempArr2 = tempArr[1].split('(Work notes)');

        internalDate = tempArr[0]; // >> 08.03.2018 09:53:37
        internalName = tempArr2[0]; // >> Mustermann, Max
        internalNote = tempArr2[1]; // >> Work note internal
```

When I, for example, have the following String

> var intNote = "08.03.2018 09:53:37 - Mustermann, Max (Work notes) Work
>   note -  internal"

I get the result

```
internalNote = tempArr2[1]; // >> Work note
```

I know the 'problem' is the operator `.split('-')`. How can I define it to split only at the first given "-" that my result will be

```
internalNote = tempArr2[1]; // >> Work note - internal
```

Comment: do you have always a timestamp in front of the text?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes I do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you could use regex all the way.

```
/([^-]*)-(.*)\(Work notes\)(.*)/
```

will give you three capture groups (no. 1-3) with the strings you're after.

```js
var intNote1 = "08.03.2018 09:53:37 - Mustermann, Max (Work notes) Work note internal",
    intNote2 = "08.03.2018 09:53:37 - Mustermann, Max (Work notes) Work note - internal",
    re = /([^-]*)-(.*)\(Work notes\)(.*)/,
    arr;
    
arr=re.exec(intNote1);
arr.shift();            // Remove index 0 (full match)
document.write('<br/>1:' + intNote1 + '<br/>' + arr.join('<br/>'));

arr=re.exec(intNote2);
arr.shift();            // Remove index 0 (full match)
document.write('<br/><br/>2:' + intNote2 + '<br/>' + arr.join('<br/>'));
```

Comment: This solution is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of first `split`, use `substring`

```
var internalDate = intNote.substring( 0, intNote.indexOf( '-' ) );
var tempArr1  = intNote.substring( intNote.indexOf( '-' ) + 1 );
var tempArr2 = tempArr1.split('(Work notes)');

internalDate = tempArr[0]; // >> 08.03.2018 09:53:37
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide a regex to split.

Check this.

```js
var intNote = "08.03.2018 09:53:37 - Mustermann, Max (Work notes) Work note - internal"
var tempArr = intNote.split(/-(.+)/)
        var tempArr2 = tempArr[1].split('(Work notes)');

        internalDate = tempArr[0]; 
        internalName = tempArr2[0]; 
        internalNote = tempArr2[1]; 
        
        console.log(internalDate)
        console.log(internalName)
        console.log(internalNote)
```